# Why cls.__getattribute__ returns a function instead of a bound method whereas cls.__call__ returns a bound method

Tags: python, getattribute, python-descriptors

Suppose `cls` is a class in python. `cls.__getattribute__` returns the `__getattribute__` function defined on `object`, but it doesn't bind `cls` to this function. According to the descriptor protocol, `cls` is an instance of `object` and if an attribute is found on the class dictionary, it should return a bound method with `cls` bound to it.

The same call with `cls.__call__` returns a bound method with `cls` bound to the `__call__` function defined on `type`. Why is there a difference? Also why doesn't `cls.__getattribute__` find the attribute in `type`?

```
class cls:
    pass

 [In]: cls.__getattribute__
[Out]: slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>
 [In]: object.__getattribute__
[Out]: <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>
 [In]: cls.__getattribute__ is object.__getattribute__
[Out]: True
 [In]: cls.__call__
[Out]: <method-wrapper '__call__' of type object at 0x7fdee07ad110>
 [In]: type.__call__.__get__(cls)
[Out]: <method-wrapper '__call__' of type object at 0x7fdee07ad110>
```

Comment: Both are implementation details of CPython; it's probably not worth worrying about the difference. See https://discuss.python.org/t/difference-between-slot-wrapper-method-wrapper-and-wrapper-descriptor/14184/7

Comment: @chepner: The question isn't about the particular implementation-detail types used to represent the methods. It's about, why is `__getattribute__` unbound and `__call__` bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look up `cls.__getattribute__`, that gets found in `cls`'s own MRO, on `cls`'s superclass `object`. Like any other method found this way, the lookup returns an unbound method representing the `__getattribute__` method of instances of the class.

On the other hand, when you look up `cls.__call__`, that doesn't get found in `cls`'s MRO. `cls`'s MRO is `(cls, object)`, and neither `cls` nor `object` defines a `__call__` method. Instead, this method gets found on `cls`'s own class, its *metaclass*: it gets found on `type`. As with any other method found this way, the resulting method is bound to the instance the lookup happened on, that instance being `cls` itself.

Thus, `cls.__getattribute__` represents the unbound method for getting attributes on instances of `cls`, while `cls.__call__` represents a bound method for calling `cls` itself.